# How to avoid redundant catching exceptions of mocked methods which can throws exceptions according interface

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, mocking

I have following code in my unit test:

```
 when(workspaceMock.getNamespaceRegistry()).thenReturn(namespaceRegistryMock);
```

method `getNamespaceRegistry` can throws `IOException`

In terms of java mentioned row is method call and I should to catch it.

But on another hand I understand that this method cannot throw exception because I set this method behaviour there. And it is looks redundant to catch exception here.

Can you clarify this situation and advise best practises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to make your test method declare `throws Exception`. Normally, you don't want to do this on *production* code, of course, but it's standard practice in *test* code.